# Python program counts self as an argument and a causes a TypeError

Tags: python

```
class Shirt:

    def __init__(self, shirt_color, shirt_size, shirt_style, shirt_price):
        self.color = shirt_color
        self.size = shirt_size
        self.style = shirt_style
        self.price = shirt_price

    def change_price(self, new_price):
        self.price = new_price

    def discount(self, discount):
        return self.price * (1 - discount)

from shirt import Shirt

shirt_one = Shirt('red', 'M', 'long-sleeved, 45')
shirt_two = Shirt('orange', 'S', 'short-sleeved, 30')

print(shirt_one.price)
print(shirt_two.color)

shirt_two.change_price(45)
print(shirt_two.price)
```

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: @ItamarMushkin no, it was already there but I missed it because of the old formatting

Comment: People shouldn't downvote a troubleshooting question. That's what StackOverflow is for. Finding mistakes and pointing the poster to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shirt_one = Shirt('red', 'M', 'long-sleeved, 45')
shirt_two = Shirt('orange', 'S', 'short-sleeved, 30')
```

should probably be

```
shirt_one = Shirt('red', 'M', 'long-sleeved', '45')
shirt_two = Shirt('orange', 'S', 'short-sleeved', '30')
```

You are expecting 4 arguments (5 if self included)

```
def __init__(self, shirt_color, shirt_size, shirt_style, shirt_price):
```

but you are passing 3 arguments.